# How can I check for differences - Local vs Live

Tags: 8, testing

I have a fairly large D8 instance with a ton of content and our deployment process does not include automated testing at all. This means that for all of our changes, we literally go through all pages and compare side by side local vs live to see 1) that our change is working and 2) that there are no unintended side effects of said changes (mostly for design/front-end). I was curious to know if there was an easy way to have live vs local compared auto-magically? I think that side by side comparison for super small changes is a bit inefficient.

Just as a side note: I just started at this job 2 days ago so side-by-side comparison is the only way that I would be able to actually check differences until I get a solid understanding of the site. We are a 3 man dev team for a large multi-millionaire institution so bandwidth is tight and it looks like whatever the solution is, it'll have to be a 1 man project for now.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fairly broad question... the only place to start, is with writing the first test for the next change you make, whether it is unit, kernel or functional and go from there. There should not be a need to company every page manually, for that you'd want some sort of visual regression testing (if thats what you mean) to compare. If you are comparing pixels/placement/position, thats what you will want. It will take time to build up to that point, but as a one man team, it will pay off in time savings.

Comment: If you are just comparing things like "does this field output the value correctly" vs "is this pixel perfect" vs "is my service firing" all all very different test layers. I suppose you could start here: https://www.cypress.io/ but a majority of my tests are the unit/kernel layer with occasional functional tests with headless chrome.

Comment: @Kevin - I definitely agree my question was broad and that is because the team is literally side by side comparing everything from functionality to visual changes. I appreciate your feedback and I'll check out cypress.io. Thank you so much!

Comment: Understanding _what_ to test (add value) is definitely harder than writing the test. You certainly don't want to waste time writing tests that provide no value, so figuring out what to cover is a good first step. If you have never written tests before, unit tests are the easiest to begin with. With an established codebase it feels like a daunting task, at this point you can only go case by case basis and build a test suite(s) as you touch code. Note that Cypress is not part of Drupal stack, Drupal ships with PHPUnit and Nightwatch.js.

Comment: I recommend to use Behat to test the site, at least certain functionalities. There are visual regression tools as well, you may try them. Manual testing is error prone and mental health killer. I understand you have just started your job there, that's why I think you should convince your boss to use testing. It's like working with a safety net.